# D3.js Making multiple selections from a checkbox and filter the nodes and links based on the selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I am looking to modify my existing my forced directed graph and make it a bit more flexible. 
Below is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/tgv6s5cd/19/). Right now there are radio buttons to control the opacity of nodes and links. There are 4 node types:

```
   Agent,Customer,Phone,ID_Card
```

Clicking on either radio buttons will reduce the opacity of all the nodes and links except the selected node and it's incoming and outgoing links.

I am trying to add checkboxes instead of a radio button so that multiple selections can be made.

So , for instance if s is the set of selections then you will make any node opaque where node in s
and any links opaque where start_node in s AND end_node in s.

For example if "Customer" and "Agent" nodes are selected then all the Customer,Agent nodes should be opaque and as well as all the links between them.

If "Customer" , "Agent", "ID_Card" is selected all the 3 nodes and all the links between "Customer" and "Agent" , "Agent" and "ID_Card" and "Customer" and "ID_card" should be opaque.

Also , unchecking of the nodes should be handled and graph should get filtered accordingly

Below is the **HTML**:

```
      <div id="map"></div>
      <div id="legend">
  <h3>Filter</h3>
  <div class="input-group" id="filters">
  <script>/*<<label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="all" > All</label>
    <br />
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Customer"> type=Customer</label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Phone"> type=Phone</label>
   <br />
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="ID_Card"> type=ID_Card</label>
   <br />
```

Below is my **JSON**

```
    var IDData = JSON.stringify([
  ["node/105173", "node/38180995", "Agent", "Customer", "1379644.0", 1, 264, "1374903"],
  ["node/1061", "node/21373542", "Agent", "Customer", "530848.0", 1, 3000, "529502"],
  ["node/10750", "node/59648369", "Agent", "Customer", "1454228.0", 1, 120, "1454118"],
  ["node/10750", "node/78569210", "Agent", "Customer", "1425251.0", 1, 234, "1421416"],
  ["node/10750", "node/96726118", "Agent", "Customer", "1376239.0", 1, 434, "1376152"],
  ["node/10946829", "node/11190", "Customer", "Agent", "1409620.0", 20, 3380, "1406665"],
  ["node/10946829", "node/57774036", "Customer", "Customer", "1460029.0", 3, 960, "1459731"],
  ["node/109947", "node/97911872", "Agent", "Customer", "1323025.0", 1, 600, "1315582"],...])
```

I parse through this dynamic JSON data and make it in a format suitable to render the graph with the below piece of javascript code:

```
         var galData = JSON.parse(IDData);
var startnodes = [];
var endnodes = [];
var startnodetype = [];
var endnodetype = [];
var PayTime = [];
var TXN_COUNT = [];
var Total_Amt = [];
var SendTime = [];
galData.map(function(e, i) {
  startnodes.push(e[0]);
  endnodes.push(e[1]);
  startnodetype.push(e[2]);
  endnodetype.push(e[3]);
  PayTime.push(e[4]);
  TXN_COUNT.push(e[5]);
  Total_Amt.push(e[6]);
  SendTime.push(e[7]);
});
var final_data = createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, PayTime, TXN_COUNT, Total_Amt, SendTime);
makeGraph("#Network_graph", final_data);
```

In order to make the checkbox work I have tried below piece of code:

```
     d3.selectAll("input[name=filter]").on("change", function(d) {
  var filter = document.getElementsByName('filter')

  var value = []

    var value[i]= this.value;

    node.style("opacity", 1);
    link.style("opacity", 1);
for(var i = 0; i < filter.length; ++i) {
if filter[i].checked {
    if (value[i] !== "all") {
      node.filter(function(d) {
          return d.type != value[i]; //this 
        })
        .style("opacity", "0.2");

        }}})
```

This piece should filter the nodes and only keep the checked nodes as opaque:

using a similar approach I plan to keep the selected links opaque:

```
link.filter(function(d) {
      return d.source.type != value[i] &&
        d.target.type != value[i];
    })
    .style("opacity", "0.2");

  link.filter(function(d) {
      return d.source.type == value[i] &&
        d.target.type == value[i];
    })
    .style("opacity", "1");
}
```

But I am not getting this to work. Still learning Javascript/d3.js. So , looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with checkboxes, you have to inspect *all* of them to see which one is checked and which one is not. Right now, your code is dealing with checkboxes as if they were radio buttons.

Here is a solution. Inside the `.on("change"` function, we'll discover what checkboxes are checked:

```
function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
    var checkboxesChecked = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].defaultValue);
        }
    }
    return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : " ";
}
```

And then we'll populate an array (here named `checkedBoxes`):

```
var checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes("checkb");
```

Using that array, we'll set the opacity of your nodes and links:

```
node.filter(function(d) {
        return checkedBoxes.indexOf(d.type) < 0;
    })
    .style("opacity", "0.2");

link.filter(function(d) {
        return checkedBoxes.indexOf(d.source.type) < 0 &&
            checkedBoxes.indexOf(d.target.type) < 0;
    })
    .style("opacity", "0.2");

link.filter(function(d) {
        return checkedBoxes.indexOf(d.source.type) > -1 &&
            checkedBoxes.indexOf(d.target.type) > -1;
    })
    .style("opacity", "1");
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcbpvev6/

PS: you'll have to create a special condition for the "All" checkbox.

Comment: Excellent solution. One last very minor thing. I only want those links to be opaque when 2 connecting nodes are opaque. Right now if a node is opaque then all it's outgoing and incoming links appear opaque.

Comment: Instead of `&&` use `||`. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/q7m1mLbo/